# Using beautiful soup to pull text from multiple <tr>'s

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The goal is to output a dictionary of course names and their grade from this:

```
<tr>
<td class="course"><a href="/courses/1292/grades/5610">Modern Europe &amp; the World - Dewey</a></td>
<td class="percent">
    92%
</td>
<td style="display: none;"><a href="#" title="Send a Message to the Teacher" class="no-hover"><img alt="Email" src="/images/email.png?1395938788" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

to this:

```
{Modern Europe &amp; the World - Dewey: 92%, the next couse name: grade...etc}
```

I know how to find just the percent tag or just the a href tag but I'm unsure how to get the text and compile it into a dictionary so it's more usable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each `tr` contains a sequence of `td` elements containing the information you want, you just need to use `find_all()` to collect them into a list, and then extract the information you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<tr>
<td class="course"><a href="/courses/1292/grades/5610">Modern Europe &amp; the World - Dewey</a></td>
<td class="percent">
    92%
</td>
<td style="display: none;"><a href="#" title="Send a Message to the Teacher" class="no-hover"><img alt="Email" src="/images/email.png?1395938788" /></a></td>
</tr>
""")

grades = {}

for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    td_text = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")]
    grades[td_text[0]] = td_text[1]
```

Result:

```
>>> grades
{u'Modern Europe & the World - Dewey': u'92%'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 For each `tr` element, try to find children what you need (those who has `course`, and `percent` class) 
If both exists, then build the `grades` dict

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """
... <tr>
... <td class="course"><a href="/courses/1292/grades/5610">Modern Europe &amp; the World - Dewey</a></td>
... <td class="percent">
...     92%
... </td>
... <td style="display: none;"><a href="#" title="Send a Message to the Teacher" class="no-hover"><img alt="Email" src="/images/email.png?1395938788" /></a></td>
... </tr>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> grades  = {}
>>> for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
...     td_course  = tr.find("td", {"class" : "course"})
...     td_percent = tr.find("td", {"class" : "percent"})
...     if td_course and td_percent:
...         grades[td_course.text.strip()] = td_percent.text.strip()
... 
>>> 
>>> grades
{u'Modern Europe & the World - Dewey': u'92%'}
```